# How do create this type of json reponse in React Js (Node Js API)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native-calendars

I got this response from Node Js API, and I want to change the reponse in react js as like below.

Node js API Response i got

```
[
    {
        "selected": true,
        "date": "2021-01-15",
        "selectedColor": "#2ecc71"
    },
    {
        "selected": true,
        "date": "2021-01-16",
        "selectedColor": "#e74c3c"
    },
]
```

I want this response from above JSON value

```
markedDates={{
    '2021-01-15': {selected: true, selectedColor: '#e74c3c'},
    '2021-01-16': {selected: true, selectedColor: '#2980b9'}
}}
```

Comment: Have you tried processing that response into the form you want? What happened?

Answer (score 1):

You can transform your input array into the desired format with the use of [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like so:

```
const data = [
    {
        "selected": true,
        "date": "2021-01-15",
        "selectedColor": "#2ecc71"
    },
    {
        "selected": true,
        "date": "2021-01-16",
        "selectedColor": "#e74c3c"
    },
];

const markedDates = data.reduce((a, c) => ({
    ...a, 
    [c.date]: { 
        selected: c.selected, 
        selectedColor: c.selectedColor
    }
}), {});
```

The reduce operation iterates over the input array, and in this case we append a key of the current item (`c` in the example) to the accumulated (`a` in the example) value. We shorten the code even further by using new ES6 operators such as returning an object literal and using the spread operator, [which is also showcased on the JS docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#spread_properties)

Answer (score 1):

Working code with ES6:

```
const input = [
  {
      "selected": true,
      "date": "2021-01-15",
      "selectedColor": "#2ecc71"
  },
  {
      "selected": true,
      "date": "2021-01-16",
      "selectedColor": "#e74c3c"
  },
]

const format = input => {
  const obj = {};
  input.forEach(inp => {
    const { selected, date, selectedColor } = inp;
    obj[date] = { selected, selectedColor };
  });
  return obj;
}

console.log(format(input));
```